# Is it possible to write an IF inline in HTML for a blade template

Tags: html, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I have a checkbox element in my blade template and I want to know if it is possible to write an if statement inside of a html element.

This works:

```
@if($data->holiday)
   <div class="input-field">
      <input placeholder="" name="holiday" id="holiday" checked
       type="checkbox"
       value="1">
       <label for="holiday">Holiday</label>
   </div>
@else
   <div class="input-field">
       <input placeholder="" name="holiday" id="holiday" 
        type="checkbox"
        value="1">
        <label for="holiday">Holiday</label>
   </div>
@endif
```

Due to the doublecode I want to write something like this:

```
    <div class="input-field">
          <input placeholder="" name="holiday" id="holiday"

           {{if($data->holiday)?'checked':'' }}

           //or

           @if($data->holiday)?'checked':''@endif

           type="checkbox"
           value="1">
           <label for="holiday">Holiday</label>
    </div>
```

But inside the input tag the code generates a bunch of errors. Is there something special to know or do I have to do it like in my first example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<input placeholder="" name="holiday" id="holiday" {{ ($data->holiday) ? "checked" : "" }} type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Answer (score 5):

use as this code

```
<div class="input-field">
      <input placeholder="" name="holiday" id="holiday"

       {{ ($data->holiday)?'checked':'' }}

       //or

       @if($data->holiday) 'checked' @endif

       type="checkbox"
       value="1">
       <label for="holiday">Holiday</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" {{ ($icv->ic_to_unit_fk == $uv->unit_pkey)? 'checked="true"' : '' }}>
```